# How to update my version of git on OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I'm on OSX 10.8.2 and I'm running git git v1.7.4.4

I just installed git on a remote server and it's version 1.11.x. I'm I would like to be running the same version of the software but I cannot figure out how to update git on my laptop.

I attempted to follow the steps listed [here](http://www.eatplaycode.com/how-to-install-git-in-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8/), which instruct to download the [git-OSX-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list), run the install (which ran smoothly) and then do:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git
```

But after this I do `git --version` and it's still 1.7.4.4. Did I just reinstall the same version? Or did I install a newer version somewhere else?

I've been reading similar questions and I think the issue is that OSX ships with an old version of git installed in a different location then where the git-osx-installer or mac ports will put it. But I'm not sure how to correct this. Thanks in advance for your advice.

Update:

`which git` returns: 
/usr/bin/git

`echo $PATH` returns: 
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

Update2:

```
ESL ~/Downloads$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
ESL ~/Downloads$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
ESL ~/Downloads$ 
ESL ~/Downloads$ git --version
git version 1.8.1.3
```

It appears I installed the newer git version in local. So should I add the `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to my .bash_profile? Is it a problem that both versions of git are installed?

I added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the bottom of my ~/.bash_profile and now the new version of git runs.

Comment: what is `which git`displaying? does the result of `echo $PATH` contain `/usr/local/bin` ?

Comment: I added both of those to the question above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since /usr/bin shows up before /usr/local/bin in your path, the git executable in /usr/bin will be given precedence.
try this in your shell:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
which git
```

On a side note, I'd strongly recommend using [homebrew](https://brew.sh) for managing installations such as this on macos

Comment: I added the results of your test above, with some corresponding questions.

Comment: no its not a problem that you've got both version installed - you can add that export line in to your ~/.bashrc and from then onwards the version in /usr/local/bin will always take precedence.

Comment: At this point, should I still consider homebrew or just leave what I have? I don't know much about package managers, so I'd be curious to hear why you strongly recommended it.

Comment: I would definitely recommend installing homebrew - though if you're on a tight deadline - making further changes to your mac might not be a great idea for today :) Homebrew does a few great things - the most relevant in this case I think might be : 1) ensures that all packages that you install are installed in safe 'sandboxed' locations (i.e. not polluting your /usr/bin directly). 2)  keeping track of whats installed and their associated versions, 3) allows you to switch between versions painlessly.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into homebrew. Is there anything about my current location of git that I should correct? Will homebrew fix it?

Comment: I think the current location should be fine - once you start installing software with home-brew - it will link the installed version to /usr/local/bin which will simply override the symlink you've created (for git).

Comment: I installed the new version of git with homebrew. Then I erased the git file in /usr/bin and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

The best way to update any binary on a Mac OSX machine is to use the package(s) developed specifically for Mac (a .dmg or .pkg download).

In the case of git this is at: http://git-scm.com/download/mac
(clicking on this link should automatically start the download of the latest version of git for Mac).

However, in this case (at least for my 10.8.3 MacBook) this was not quite the whole story: the package installs git in `/usr/local/git` and then adds that path at the end of `$PATH` - which defeats the whole purpose IMO.

I have manually modified my `.bashrc` so as to have something similar to what suggested above:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Once you do that, you should see the correct version of git being picked:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.2.2
```

Note that this won't work for any app that is launched interactively (eg, via the docking bar) - you'll have to run the additional script provided in the downloaded package; see the `README` for instructions.

Comment: Is there an easy way to undo this change? I just want to test if another method I've tried works.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue in Cygwin (linux environment compiled for windows). I would do

```
which git
```

and it would respond with the correct location of the updated git compiled from source, but wouldn't actually use it until I did

```
hash -r git
```

I don't claim to understand what this did or why it had to be done, but after that `git --version` replied with '1.8.2.rc0.22.gb3600c3' which was clearly no longer the old git shipped with Cygwin. This may not apply to OSX, but give it a shot if `which git` is locating the updated binary.

Comment: I added my `which git` and a `$PATH` to the question. Does this change you advice at all?

Comment: Not really, just try `hash -r git` and then see what `git --version` gives you.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that shell uses hash-tables for storing executables' paths. You can also restart the shell, it will also clear the hash table. For further details: http://crashingdaily.wordpress.com/2008/04/21/hashing-the-executables-a-look-at-hash-and-type/

Comment: I have problem with with one, shell returns `hash: too many arguments`.